# How do you declare component states in ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

In mxml you declare states like this:

```
<box:states>
    <s:State name="active"/>
    <s:State name="disabled"/>
</box:states>
```

How do you acheive the same in an ActionScript class? Apparently it's the same in Flex 3 and Flex 4, whatever it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. Here's what I came up with:

```
// constructor
public function MyBox() {
    states = new Array();

    for each (var name:String in ['working', 'active', 'disabled']) {
        var state:State = new State();
        state.name = name;
        states.push(state);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can avoid it, do!

That said, hold your breath!

That said, take a look at the [State](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/states/State.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) Class.  Create a new instance and define the overrides.  I believe all the overrides are link in the "see also" link.

Each component has a "[states](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#states)" array.

So, just create the states manually.  Add the relevant overrides, and add that state to the states array.

It isn't hard, but it can be pretty tedious.  I did this for the Flextras Calendar.

Comment: @Wade Mueller Thanks!  I think we're trading for a lot of the questions lately.

Comment: Thanks yeah it worked, it turned out that I was totally confused between view states and skin states. They don't exactly make the difference clear in tutorials.

Comment: It's a Flex 4 thing I haven't completely assimilated.  But, it relates directly to the skin controlling layout.  In theory, in a Spark component you won't ever be modifying the component's state, only the skin state.  In a Halo style component, you won't ever use the skin state [as they don't exist].